# unable to create android app using apache cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I tried to create android app using `Apache Cordova` using the following command

```
C:\Users\krishna\cordova-3.0.0\cordova-android\bin>
create C:\Users\krishna\workspace3\SampleApp2 com.example.sampphonegap SamplePhonegapApp
```

It niether shows error nor creates the app at specified location.
Please help me solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here its better explain : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: This one explains for linux and not for windows

Comment: do you want to create for Android in windows?

Comment: yes i want for windows only